# elasticsearch Saved Search with Group by

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl

```
index_name: my_data-2020-12-01
ticket_number: T123 
ticket_status: OPEN 
ticket_updated_time: 2020-12-01 12:22:12   

index_name: my_data-2020-12-01 
ticket_number: T124 
ticket_status: OPEN 
ticket_updated_time: 2020-12-01 12:32:11   

index_name: my_data-2020-12-02 
ticket_number: T123 
ticket_status: INPROGRESS 
ticket_updated_time: 2020-12-02 12:33:12   

index_name: my_data-2020-12-02 
ticket_number: T125 
ticket_status: OPEN 
ticket_updated_time: 2020-12-02 14:11:45
```

I want to create a saved search with group by  ticket_number field get unique doc with latest ticket status (ticket_status). Is it possible?

Comment: can you please share your expected search result?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply query again, I am assuming you are using Kibana for visualization purpose. in your query, you need to filter based on the `ticket_number` and sort based on `ticket_updated_time`.

**Working example**

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "ticket_updated_time": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "ticket_number" :{
                "type" : "text"
            },
            "ticket_status" : {
                "type" : "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample docs**

```
{
    "ticket_number": "T123",
    "ticket_status": "OPEN",
    "ticket_updated_time": "2020-12-01T12:22:12"
}

{
    "ticket_number": "T123",
    "ticket_status": "INPROGRESS",
    "ticket_updated_time": "2020-12-02T12:33:12"
}
```

Now as you can see, both the sample documents belong to the same ticket_number with different status and updated time.

**Search query**

```
{
    "size" : 1, // fetch only the latest status document, if you remove this, will get other ticket with different status.
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "ticket_number": "T123"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "ticket_updated_time": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**And search result**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "65180491",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "ticket_number": "T123",
                    "ticket_status": "INPROGRESS",
                    "ticket_updated_time": "2020-12-02T12:33:12"
                },
                "sort": [
                    1606912392000
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Comment: How can I create visualizations (Pie chart)?

Comment: @Kapila, you can try it yourself, so please ask a followup question dedicated to Kibana visualization but the same query(posted by me) answers your original question and will be useful to create visualization(as it depends on the search query at the end in backend)

Comment: I understood but what I meant in my original question was saved search in discover, not using Search API.

Comment: @Kapila yeah, I don't have much exp with Kibana but as mentioned earlier you can ask a follow-up question and get the response from community members

Answer (score 0):

If you need to group by `ticket_number` field, then you can use aggregation as well

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ticket_updated_time": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
 {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ticket_number.keyword",
        "order": {
          "latestOrder": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latestOrder": {
          "max": {
            "field": "ticket_updated_time"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"buckets": [
        {
          "key": "T125",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "latestOrder": {
            "value": 1.606918305E12,
            "value_as_string": "2020-12-02 14:11:45"
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "T123",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "latestOrder": {
            "value": 1.606912392E12,
            "value_as_string": "2020-12-02 12:33:12"
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "T124",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "latestOrder": {
            "value": 1.606825931E12,
            "value_as_string": "2020-12-01 12:32:11"
          }
        }
      ]
```

Comment: How to create a visualization (Pie chart)?